# only for or for only

Tags: grammar, emphasis, for

which is correct?

1.it is on sale only for $25.

2.it is on sale for only $25.

I know it is easier to say :

it is only $25.

but I want to know which is correct.

Comment: It's better to put _only_ directly before the word that it modifies. Here, the low price is emphasised, so (2) is more idiomatic.

Comment: I would consider 'on sale only for $25' to mean 'on sale at $25, and not at any other price, lower or higher' and 'on sale at only $25' to mean 'on sale at the low price of $25'. As Kate says, 'only' modifies what it comes directly before.